# i can't launch eclipse i get errorcode =6

Tags: java, eclipse, error-code

i have reinstalled eclipse, java and the JDK to the newest 64bit version
i have a variable environment named PATH with a varible of

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\client\jvm.dll

After double left-clicking eclipse.exe
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVtTt.jpg

After pressing ok I get the error:

**Java was started but returned exit code=6**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvpaY.jpg)

This is my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Programs in `Program Files (x86)` are normally 32 bit. You need a 64 bit JDK/JRE for 64 bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is with java versions, uninstall all java versions from your computer and install 1.6 required one as it was mentions in the settings you posted, it should fix.

Regadrs..

Comment: That setting has nothing to do with the version of Java. It just indicates either 1.6 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple java path included in your PATH variable.

Firstly clean that up.

Make sure you have one single JDK installed and the same should be referred by your JAVA_HOME variable.(Create a JAVA_HOME variable and include it in path like ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;)

Then you unzinp eclipse and just double click eclipse to run it.

I could not understand the use of jvm.dll???

We just install jdk and set it in env var and double click eclipse. that's it.

example - if you installed jdk1.7 then you keep your JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

AND PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specifiy the JRE bin/ folder in your PATH-Variable.

Remove this other's paths, there mostly useless. Maybe add the bin/ path from the JDK (for compiling via CMD), but eclipse don't need it, because eclipse has his own java compiler (included in the JDT).

And be aware, that you need a x86_64 Eclipse when you use a x86_64 Java Virtual Machine.

```
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\"
```

for example should be enough. You could remove the other entries..

Edit: Oh and remove the following line in the eclipse.ini (eclipse-folder)

```
-vm

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

If you have removed this entry, eclipse will automatically take the java from your PATH-Variable.

Just for your information:

**Eclipse will detect java in this way:**

1: Look for a jre/ folder within the eclipse-dir.

2: Look for a -vm parameter in the eclipse.ini

3: Look in the PATH variable

[FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-startup` and add `-vm` using `jvm dll` instead of `javaw.exe` on top of the `eclipse.ini` file as follows:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```